# NoMethodError undefined method `code'

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am not sure what went wrong as when user registers it shows a undefined method `code' error that points to ' if @user.save' from the users controller under def create. I have looked back at the history of my controller and nothing has changed. Not sure why it is breaking now or how to fix it.

user model:

```
  validates :code, uniqueness: true
  validates_format_of :zip_code,
                  with: /\A\d{5}-\d{4}|\A\d{5}\z/,
                  message: "should be 12345 or 12345-1234"
```

Comment: what's your User model look like?

Comment: I just added the user model

Comment: You're validating an attribute named `:code`. Are you sure it exists?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the only `code` in your code is here:

```
#user.rb
validates :code, uniqueness: true
```

Did you add this later and forget to run `rake db:migrate` perhaps?  or could there be multiple instances of `:code` with the same value?